# How to authenticate a user with Firebase Apple Authentication using expo-apple-authentication?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

How to authenticate a user with Firebase Apple Authentication using expo-apple-authentication? I tried this below

```
import { getAuth,  OAuthProvider } from "firebase/auth";
import * as AppleAuthentication from 'expo-apple-authentication';

const auth = getAuth();

const appleCredential = await AppleAuthentication.signInAsync();

const provider = new OAuthProvider('apple.com');
const authCredential = provider.credential({
    idToken: appleIdToken,
    rawNonce: unhashedNonce,
});

// Sign in with credential form the Apple user.
signInWithCredential(auth, authCredential)
    .then((result) => {
        // User signed in.
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

However I am getting this error :

> Firebase: The audience in ID Token [host.exp.Exponent] does not match the expected audience. (auth/invalid-credential).